# <> becomes &lt &gt in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Assume I have item `div`, `div` is a beautifulsoup object (obtained by findAll). The source looks like:

```
<div>text1 <span>text2</span></div>
```

What I want to do is to replace text1 with text3. I tried:

1. `div.string.replace_with(newstr), where newstr="text3 <span>text2</span>"`
   This does not work because div.string is None
2. `div.replace_with(newstr)`
   This does not work because the final result shows `&lt` and`&gt` rather than "<" and ">" when I save the html code into file.

Comment: Which parser you are using? Try with lxml

Comment: Do you mean the feature attribute in at initialization Beautifulsoup(...,features='lxml'). I already did that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find `div` tag and then find `next_element` which is `text1` and then `replace_with` `text3`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html= '''<div>text1 <span>text2</span></div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
soup.find('div').next_element.replace_with('text3')
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just playing around with the interactive prompt... I'm sure there's a better solution but...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<div>text1 <span>text2</span></div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features="lxml")
div = soup.find('div')
a, *b = div.contents
c = a.replace('text1', 'text3')
a.replace_with(c)
print(div)
```